# Split the data on a worksheet in Excel and keep it independent

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating schedule and Gantt chart on a spreadsheet. I need to split this data on two vertical windows on the same worksheet. 
Split command under 'View' splits the same worksheet in different windows and shows all the data on both windows. I need to display schedule in one windows and Gantt chart in other. How do I do this?

Basically, on a single worksheet, I want to

```
1. freeze panes horizontally at some specified row
2. split panes vertically at some specified column
3. and when I split panes vertically, want to actually split the data and not have copies on the same workbook created on left and
right side of split line.
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Split` use `New Window` command (still in `View`), then click `Arrange all`, select the desired arrangement and check `Windows of active workbook`. This will show the same workbook in two different windows and you will be able to navigate in them independently.

Comment: this creates two separate instances of workbook.. I want what split command does in the same workbook but need to have those splited ones to have different data.. basically have two worksheets displayed on one worksheet

Comment: excel can display only one worksheet in one window, I don't know any direct solution to your answer. Why two instances doesn't work for you?

Comment: if you see this link   https://www.smartsheet.com/blog/gantt-chart-excel,  what I want to do is what is shown in 2nd picture.

Comment: Basically I want to split the worksheet and have data edition independent in both windows or at least hide some columns in one windows but keep those visible in other

Comment: What you've linked is indeed the functionality of `split`, why that doesn't work for you? Please don't answer here but edit your question.

Comment: I have edited the question to include my specific requirements.